# Blocking hard and master reset or internet access permanently on Samsung Galaxy phone

Tags: factory-reset, samsung

I have a porn problem and I want to either disable the ability to do hard or master resets on the Samsung Galaxy phone (the only way to get by certain site blockers of which I have setup an undecipherable password), or simply block all internet access on the phone while still allowing calls to be made. How can this be done so that I will never again be tempted to view obscene material?

Comment: I doubt blocking resets can be done. And even if you could block internet access probably a reset would enable it. If your habit is affecting your day-to-day life you don't need a technical solution, you need to talk to a professional.

Answer (score 1):

1.You can install one of [parental control apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=parental%20control&hl=en) and ask your friend to set password for you (if you are ashamed you can tell that this is e.g. for your son or sister...).

2.If you have rooted phone [that topic is for you !](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?s=9cde42ab0a4f6d1b5b85c2e81d4920ff&t=1756137) Made this application as the system app and then unroot your phone.

I think in your case best solution is using both methods above.